# All non-name words ending with ize

Tags: verbs, endings

Are all non-name words ending with `ize` *always* semantically interpreted as verbs in the English language?

*Update*: I just found a few: maize, prize that aren't. One about checking for two or more syllables before the ize? Is that a reliant method?

Comment: If you wait a few minutes, @tchrist can call up a list for you. ^_^ Absent that, look at the context as a better way to determine whether something is being used as a noun or a verb.

Comment: Also, don't forget that in British English, the equivalent is **-ise**, which complicates things wonderfully, since more non-verbs end in that than do in **-ize**.

Comment: @Robusto What size list are you looking for? :)

Comment: This question fascinated me. The first word that came to mind was *moisturize*. I looked it up, and apparently the first known usage was 1945. This got me to wondering if the first noun with "ize" (having 2 syllables - so it seems like a suffix) becoming a verb, was responsible for the "ize" suffix meaning: to "do" the root. The noun I am speaking of is the product "Simoniz". The car wax product was invented in 1921, and by the mid-century in the US, *simonize* meant "to wax" one's car. Can anyone corroborate this?

Answer (score 2):

OED notes that *-ize* is a productive suffix forming verbs. However a word like *prize* doesn't have an *-ize* **suffix**. As you have found yourself, the answer is obviously "No." Words ending *-ize* are not always verbs.

The OED entry for *-ize* has...

> 1. Words that have come down from Greek, or have been at some time adopted from Greek, or formed on Greek elements.
>
>    a. With the trans. sense of ‘make or conform to, or treat in the way of, the thing expressed by the derivation’, as *baptize* (prob. the earliest *-ize* word in English), *anathematize, anatomize, ...*

*Baptize* (which is properly spelled *-ize* even in British English, because it's derived from Greek *βαπτίζειν* with a zeta ζ ) is first attested in OED in 1297. The entry for *-ize* itself has a meta-citation from 1594, indicating that the suffix had become productive by that time. It's interesting that Nash calls such words "Italianate" rather than Greek.

> 1594   T. Nashe *Christs Teares* (new ed.) To Rdr. sig. **ijv,   Reprehenders, that complain of my boystrous compound wordes, and ending my Italionate coyned verbes all in *ize.*

*Prize,* which is obviously not formed with *-ize* as a productive suffix, is found in late Middle English and first attested in that form in 1467, although a form *pris* is cited from 1250.

I put forward that there is no way of definitively finding words with a verbing *-ize* suffix other than by individual examination. That is, even identifying disyllabic words ending in an *-ize* syllable may not be sufficient. A single example is enough to prove that: ***assize*** n. OED contains 39 examples of nouns ending *-ize,* most of which are obsolete; however *supersize* (from 1876) is just about still current. But that example means that even more than one syllable before *-ize* is not reliable.

Comment: I don't think one can say "properly spelled *-ize* in British English". The preference for *-ise* is too long-standing and too widespread to consider it "improper". Some British English speakers do favour it, with the Oxford Spelling orthography being a famous example, but something once being zeta becoming s rather than z would not be the most bizarre change in the path of etymology. Your example is one that gives one argument in favour of *-ise* since there is *baptism* but not *baptizm* and so the *-ise* form visually matches the related word better.

Comment: @JonHanna *Baptise* is so spelled because of *baptism,* true. But it's that way round.